# Link separated words

Tags: linux, bash, archlinux

I would know if there is a program or a script that can link separated words in a file name with a dot (or other punctuation marks).
Example:
How are you.pdf >>> How.are.you.pdf
I did not explain myself well, I'm looking for a bash script that can rename file names

Comment: `a="How are you.pdf";echo "${a// /.}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have `How are you.pdf` in a variable you can use [parameter expansions](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#search_and_replace):

```
% a="How are you.pdf"
% echo "${a// /.}"
How.are.you.pdf
```

The above is a bash expansion and doesn't work in a POSIX shell. In that case `sed` or simulare would be needed.

To rename all files in the current directory:

```
for a in *; do
  [ -f "$a" ] || continue
  mv -- "$a" "${a// /.}"
done
```

Comment: Pardon my curiosity, but is there any reason why you're using a `csh` prompt for `bash` commands?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Never liked using `$` as a prefix as it can be misread as a parameter expansion. And never though there was a meaning - except indication a prompt - in the prefix character.

Comment: thank you both for the answer but i did not explain myself well, I'm looking for a bash script that can rename file names

Comment: @Fabiuz99 You can easily change the above to suit your needs. I edited with one example.

Comment: Thank you very much. is there any way to rename single files instead of all??

Comment: @Fabiuz99 Just use `a="hello world.pdf";mv "$a" "${a// /.}"`?

Comment: yeah, I mean if I can rename a generic file, so how i can  change hello word with the name of a file inserted from keyborad.if for example i have "file 1" and "file 2", there may be a script that ask me the name of the file so i can rename just one without change the script itself?

Comment: `read -r a; mv "$a" "${a// /.}"` And to ensure input from tty: `read -r a < /dev/tty`

Answer (score 0):

[sed](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) is your help here.

For example:

```
echo "How are you.pdf" | sed 's/ /./g'
```

The `sed` command is divided to `command/1st argument/2nd argument/command`

In our example:

> s - search
>
> [space] - the space character
>
> . - the dot character to
>   replace
>
> g - do this globally and not only for the first occurrence

Comment: thank you both for the answer but i did not explain myself well, I'm looking for a bash script that can rename file names

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called [`perl-rename`](http://man.he.net/man1/rename) sometimes called `rename` - not to be confused with [`rename` from util-linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html).

This tool take a Perl expressions and renames accordingly:

```
perl-rename 's/ /./g' *
```

The above will rename all files / directories in the current directory to add replace spaces for periods:

```
How are you.pdf      -> How.are.you.pdf
This is another.file -> This.is.another.file
```

[You can try the regex online](https://ideone.com/VtMmoE)